# How can I see the version of OS that runs on a VM

Tags: linux, kvm, qemu, libvirt, qcow2

Is there any way that I can find out from hypervisor the version of OS that I am runing on a vm. The problem is that I have an upgrade procedure that shuts down a vm, replaces the qcow2 image and then start it again with the new image. I need to know from hypervisor if the version running is the correct one.

Comment: yes sorry this is what I meant the version of OS

Comment: <emulator>/usr/libexec/qemu-kvm</emulator>

Comment: yes I am using libvirt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use virt-inspector :

```
virt-inspector <guestvm>
```

OR

```
virt-inspector <img>
```

The output will be in XML format :

```
<operatingsystems>
.
.
.
<operatingsystems>
```